# React Native Re-render Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a chat app. When I click a notification, my app opens the chat screen. But when I click a notification on the chat screen, the page does not refresh and render new data. So I would like to make the screen re-render or re-open the same page again with new paramaters.

I am using this code when I click the notification:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate("Chat",goScreenParameters);
```

I don't want to use this code:

```js
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Main' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: goScreenName,
      params:goScreenParameters                
    }),
  ],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: I think this will work for you (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not listening to props changes in your screen, this can happen if you use params in your constructor without using `getDerivedStateFromProps` or the soon to be deprecated `componentWillRecieveProps`.

Another option is to use `this.props.navigation.push` instead of `navigate` but that will create another screen rather than "refresh" the current one.